# Can not verify Installer

Tags: c#, installation, inno-setup

I want to verify my installer , I have used this source to sign my installer :

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\signtool.exe" sign /a /f "M:\cert\MyPFX.pfx" /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" /p UFMPassped "M:\Setup.exe"
```

It signed and timestamped without any error ,

but when I want to verify it , there is a error :

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\signtool.exe" verify /v /pa "M:\Setup.exe"
```

it say :

```
File Not Valid : M:\Setup.exe
```

where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of InnoSetup are you using?  I've heard of problems with signing installers created with older versions of InnoSetup.  You probably should use the latest version (v5.3.10).

If you sign the file locally (rather than on M:), does it return that error?

Comment: There is no problem with signing , it seem that I should Purchase One of verified Certificate like verisign .